# Adding SEL_CallFuncO to a CCArray

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have the following code in my cocos2d-X application that is not compiling

```
   SEL_CallFuncO func1 =callfunc_selector(BPBasketLayer::addSingleNumberBasket);
   SEL_CallFuncO func2 =callfunc_selector(BPBasketLayer::addSpawnPowerUp);
   CCArray *arr=CCArray::create();
   arr->addObject(func1);
   arr->addObject(func2);
```

Now this is giving me an error ? What am i doing wrong ?

Kind Regards

Comment: You might want to tell what the error is.

Comment: `SEL_CallFuncO` is a function pointer and you are adding it to `CCArray` which accepts only pointers to `CCObject`. You can use `std::vector` to keep references of these selectors and use `callfuncO_selector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the error is, it looks like you're using the wrong `callfunc_selector` based on how you are instantiating `func1` and `func2`.  I think you want to use `callfuncO_selector` since it takes a `CCObject*`.

From `CCObject.h`:

`typedef void (CCObject::*SEL_CallFuncO)(CCObject*);`

`#define callfuncO_selector(_SELECTOR) (SEL_CallFuncO)(&_SELECTOR)`

**Edit:**

You will need to follow what Vikas suggested in the comments and use a `std::vector` to house the function pointers since `CCArray` is for `CCObject` derived classes only.  So something like this:

`std::vector <SEL_CallFuncO> func_ptr_array;`

`func_ptr_array.push_back(callfuncO_selector(BPBasketLayer::addSingleNumberBasket));`

`func_ptr_array.push_back(callfuncO_selector(BPBasketLayer::addSpawnPowerUp));`

Comment: Thank you so much. I got it to work. Next time you are in town, i will buy you a cofeee